# Tomcat 7.0.41 Respone already commited

Tags: java, tomcat, atmosphere

We are having a problem with Tomcat 7.0.41.
Atmosphere is being used on small amount of users - approx 40. On previuos version sockets just stopped working, so we upgraded to the latest Tomcat version.

But at one moment it just stops with following message in logs:

```
Jul 2, 2013 7:52:49 PM org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl setResponseContentType
```

SEVERE: Cannot set content type. Response already committed

Only thing that user sees is:

2000
2000
ad8

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

And that is all

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us the code . It seems you are doing something after commiting the response.

Comment: Well that is the interesting part. It breaks even on simple admin page: http://pastebin.com/NTvQFeZk Where is nothing just one session controller with few methods. Server worked almost all day, and at one moment everything just stopped